# Can a windows service application share a bin folder with a web application?

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

I have some common dlls that are referenced by both a windows service application and a asp.net web application. I don't want to make separate copies of the dlls and I also don't want to put those dlls into GAC. I try to put that service application under the same root folder as the web application so that they can share the same bin folder. I am not quite sure if this will cause any problems? I did find the web application had random session timeout, but not very often. Not sure if it was caused by the shared dlls. Can somebody just give me some advice? Thanks.

Comment: It's sounds a bit odd, but it should work (if the windows service does not do anything fancy with the bin folder). The ASP.NET session timeout has nothing to do with the fact that DLLs are shared.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, check to see if your services are writing any log files into the /bin directory.  Any changes to that directory will cause the App Domain to recycle - which in turn, drops any existing sessions.

Comment: Thanks ayang. Was a victim of this myself! Had services that were running and preventing my app from starting. It only took a few hours to realize what was going on!